# How to retrieve object properties when the property name is in a variable?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to convert string from `koderesult` into object, and then thie `obj.result` should be like this >> `obj.GetReportIdResult`. on function `detail()`, `koderesult` is string, then I want to use this `koderesult` string for `obj` object. how to convert the `koderesult` string to object name?
well, I have `obj.GetReportIdResult` to get JSON Object, then I want `GetReportIdResult` is dinamic (e.g. it can change to `GetReportMyResult` or `GetReportHkResult`)
here is my function:

```
function detail(kodenegara, koderesult)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://10.80.3.73/webservice/Service1.svc/json/weeklyflash/"+kodenegara,
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
                    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                    //alert (koderesult);
                    result = eval(koderesult);
                    alert( countTypesForBulan(obj.result, "4") ); //this obj.result should be like this >> obj.GetReportIdResult
                },
                error: function () { 
                    alert("ERROR"); 
                }
            });
        }
```

here is the button to call this function:

```
<button type="button" onclick="detail('id', 'GetReportIdResult')">Display JSON String</button>
```

Comment: Nice. What does it do, what do you need... not a question yet.

Comment: That you have to do on the server side

Comment: well, on function `detail()`, `koderesult` is string, then I want to use this `koderesult` string for `obj` object. how to convert the `koderesult` string to object name?

Comment: Note: there is no need to stringify the `data` parameter and then immediately parse the result of that back to the `obj` object. Just use `data` instead of `obj`. Or rename the `data` parameter to `obj`.

Comment: @nnnnnn ouch..ok, I will update my code..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. But I think what you need is this:

```
 alert( countTypesForBulan(obj[koderesult], "4") );
```

`obj.GetReportIdResult` is same with `obj['GetReportIdResult']`.

Comment: well, I have `obj.GetReportIdResult` to get JSON Object, then I want `GetReportIdResult` is dinamic (e.g. it can change to `GetReportMyResult` or `GetReportHkResult`)

Comment: @blankon91 - It seems that `koderesult` is a string that will hold the name of the property in your object. If so then `obj[koderesult]` (as shown in xdazz's answer) is what you need. The `[]` syntax makes the property name dynamic - it gets the name from your `koderesult` variable. You don't need the `result` variable or the `eval` from your question.

Comment: UPDATE: I add `var result = koderesult;` and now it works now :)) thank you